# Angular 4 http get - Removing hash from url

Tags: angular, http, odata

When making a HTTP call, Angular is chopping off the hash and everything after it.

Example:

```
http://sub.domain.com/api/$metadata#EndpointName
```

...becomes

```
http://sub.domain.com/api/$metadata
```

Haven't been able to find a way to tell Angular to NOT modify the URL.  Any ideas?

Currently using Angular 4.0.0.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen, it's just the fragment identifier. What API are you talking to?

Comment: We're using RESTier http://odata.github.io/RESTier/ for our API and they use the hash in the URL to denote the endpoint you want metadata for.  It's odd, but it's how they do it.

Comment: I searched for `hash` in that document and could not find it. Do you have a more specific page/location in that document that discusses how it uses the hash?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the hash symbol is used to identify a location within the current document to which you want to seek, so using it to denote an endpoint on the server is semantically incorrect.

You should use query parameters for it instead of resorting to using the hash. For example, `http://sub.domain.com/api/$metadata?endpoint=EndPointName`

As far as I know, stripping the hash sign is angular's implementation of the `Http` module

Comment: Yes, I completely agree.  With that said, the url syntax is defined by RESTier, and I have no control over it.  Best practice or not, I still have to use this URL syntax to get the API metadata.

Comment: @Difinity That sounds pretty bad to me. I think you should just roll your own http client in this case

Comment: Could you try encoding or escaping the hash?

Comment: Per my reply to Deborah, encoding doesn't do anything.  What are you referring to by "escaping"?

Comment: I have not tried to do this ... so I'm just providing what I've read. What I read said this: ` If you escape the %23 string, however (as %2523), the service will receive the '#' as you want.`

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

> Fragment Parameters The fragment part of the URL, everything after a
>   hash symbol, is information that is normally used only by the client,
>   such as a browser, and not processed by the server. Therefore it is
>   uninteresting when discussing REST parameters. The only interesting
>   item is if you need to send the actual hash character as a value
>   (instead of representing the hash control symbol) to one of the
>   options. In that case you need to encode the URL.
>
> Character Encoding Special characters are encoded in the URL, by a
>   mechanism called “percent encoding”. In this mechanism any character
>   can be replaced by the percent symbol, followed by a two-digit
>   hexadecimal value of the encoded character. If special characters
>   (such as the hash character) need to be sent as actual data, they must
>   be encoded. All other characters can optionally be encoded.

Here: https://www.soapui.org/testing-dojo/best-practices/understanding-rest-headers-and-parameters.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the encodeURI() doesn't convert the # into it's percent string (%23).  When I do this manually, the server (.Net Web API) can't recognize it and rolls in pain.